# Ajax acting weirdly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so I have this simple ajax request to see if a combination of username or password exists or not.

```
<script>
  $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //send data to ajax file now
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax_handler.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
              alert(result);
            }
           });

  });
  </script>
```

**ajax_handler.php file**

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    echo "check";
```

After hitting submit, the ajax request runs and `alert(result)` alerts the entire HTML/CSS coding of the page where my `<script>` is. Why is this happening ?

Comment: is that your entire ajax_handler.php file?

Comment: Is your <script> tag closed in the ajax_handler.php page?

Comment: @PatrickEvans
No that is not the entire file. There is much more.

Comment: @SwitchCase
I dont have any js code on ajax_handler.php

Comment: if your php script does a redirection, it will returns the new HTML page ( the one your redirected to  ) maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Well, you need to `exit` or `die()` your script after `echo` else it will display everything.

Comment: Are you only returning the `echo "check";` or is there other HTML/PHP code in the page as well? If the latter, then that's your problem

Comment: @Nicolas
Correct, a login checker function was redirecting. Thank you.

Comment: @xanderpower you could redirect in your Ajax request using `window.location.href = 'myNewPage';`

Comment: you must really send json from serverside

Comment: JSON is a better option when you are making Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the PHP script from executing the rest of the page loaded.
You can do this by using `exit()` or `die()`.

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
    echo "check";
    die();
```